# Use boost::container or boost::recursive_wrapper for creating containers of incomplete types

Tags: c++, boost, incomplete-type

I need to create a structure that has a `vector<self>` as a member variable. Boost offers 2 mechanisms that achieve this:

1 - using `boost::recursive_wrapper` i.e.:

```
struct filter
{
    uint32_t id;
    std::vector< boost::recursive_wrapper< filter > > childFilters; 
};
```

2 - using `boost::container` i.e.:

```
struct filter
{
    uint32_t id;
    boost::container::vector< filter > childFilters; 
};
```

Is there any advantage with each technique? The second `boost::container` option involves less syntax, and I guess it uses a technique similar to the `boost::recursive_wrapper` internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better choice is to use `boost::container::vector`, because it allows direct access to the type stored in the vector.

The extra layer of indirection provided by `boost::recursive_wrapper` that allows the declaration of a `std::vector<self>` makes code manipulating the vector more cumbersome, because it is necessary `get` to access the actual type being held.

i.e.

```
struct filter
{
    uint32_t id;
    std::vector< boost::recursive_wrapper< filter > > childFilters; 
};

filter myFilter;

// fill myFilter .....

BOOST_FOREACH( boost::recursive_wrapper< filter > f, myFilter.childFilters )
{
    std::cout << f.get().id << "\n";
}
```

With `boost::container::vector` the example becomes:

```
struct filter
{
    uint32_t id;
    boost::container::vector< filter > childFilters; 
};

filter myFilter;

// fill myFilter .....

BOOST_FOREACH( boost::recursive_wrapper< filter > f, myFilter.childFilters )
{
    std::cout << f.id << "\n";    // no call to get()
}
```